# Android Virtual Device Manager close indtead of launching an emulator

Tags: android, windows-8.1, android-virtual-device

I installed Android SDK and AVD on my new win 8.1 (x64).
When I create a new AVD with API 17 and try to lunch it by pressing it's "start" button, AVD manager close and of course nothing would lunch.

How I can start an emulator?
I'm new in Android Development and any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: As great alternative, i would advise [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Marco. But what I can do if I want to solve this problem, not only founding a way to go from stuck in this state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce RAM on AVD's configuration. If you're starting AVD Manager from Eclipse, try to start it from icon

Comment: I create my AVD with RAM 512 and I'm sure that I have enough RAM for it. and no, I start it directly from AVD manager